# Calling a function from main in a class

Tags: c++, function, class, program-entry-point

So I defined a function in main, I want to reuse the same function in a class... So I had to re-create it in the class. My question is, is there a way to call that function from main, without having to copy and paste it in the class...?

main.cpp

```
#include "array_class.h"
#include "stack_class.h"
#include "queue_class.h"

using namespace std;


void displayText (std::string text, int sleepTime);

int main(){
}
```

Now I intend to call displayText in say, array_class

Comment: Why not re-read the first chapter?

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: `main` is a function.  You can't define other functions within it.

Comment: So you want to know how to put a function in a class without putting it in the class? You could put a stub in the class to call another function, but if you just call `main`, you will be in a recursive loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the function in a header, then link to it where you need it

*foo.h*

```
int foo();
```

*foo.cpp*

```
#include "foo.h"
int foo()
{
    return 5;
}
```

*class.cpp*

```
#include "foo.h"
int x = foo();  // just called the function
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "foo.h"
int main()
{
    int y = foo(); // called the function again
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}
```